# Snowflake UDTF not accepting anything other than a constant value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get task dependents by dynamically passing in the database name, schema name and task name using below code-

```
create or replace function get_task_dependents(taskname varchar)
returns table(dependent_name varchar) as
$$
 select name as dependent_name from table(information_schema.task_dependents(task_name => taskname, recursive => true))
$$
;

select dependent_name from table(get_task_dependents('demo_db.demo_schema.snowtask_1'))
```

This works only if I pass in a constant value.
If I try doing something like-

```
select dependent_name,s.name from stg s, table(get_task_dependents(s.database_name||'.'||s.schema_name||'.'||s.name))
;
```

it throws this error- `argument 1 to function TASK_DEPENDENTS_SCAN needs to be constant, found 'CORRELATION(SYS_VW.TASKNAME_1)'`

Can someone please provide an alternate solution to get around or a fix to the above. I have to embed these task dependencies to another sql query

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to specify the other columns you are calling from the "stg" table and you need an alias for your table function as well.
For me:

```
select dep.dependent_name
,s.name
,s.schema_name
,s.database_name
from stg AS s
,table(get_task_dependents(s.database_name||'.'||s.schema_name||'.'||s.name)) AS dep;
```

worked.

Br, TK

Comment: Still getting same error- SQL compilation error: argument 1 to function TASK_DEPENDENTS_SCAN needs to be constant, found 'CORRELATION(SYS_VW.DATABASE_NAME_0) || '.' || CORRELATION(SYS_VW.SCHEMA_NAME_2) || '.' || CORRELATION(SYS_VW.NAME_1)'

Comment: This is part of CTE-  s4 as (
 select dep.dependent_name, s1.database_name,s1.schema_name,s1.name
   from s1 ,
   table(get_task_dependents(s1.database_name||'.'||s1.schema_name||'.'||s1.name)) as dep
   )

Comment: Ah ok, my sample table, that holds the task names only had one entry and it worked. As soon as I add another entry to the task table I get the same error as you. @Sujan is right, this is currently not implemented. 
You could do a workaround by using a stored procedure, that will loop through the table and for each entry call the get_task_dependents function.

Comment: Can't use a stored procedure here. I am trying to create a dashboard and the underlying sql uses filters as well which can only be used in expressions and not passed in as arguments to the procedure.

Comment: How often do your tasks change? Would it be possible to pre-calculate the task dependency tree with a procedure and store the results in a table? This procedure could then be called by a task with a frequency of your choice?

Comment: Update- Procedure approach resolved the issue. Thanks for helping

Comment: Glad to hear :-)

Answer (score 0):

A UDTF is a user-defined function (UDF) that returns tabular results/multiple rows. It allow you to return multiple rows for each input row.

At present the input parameters to the Snowflake UDTF are constant, it can not be dynamically obtained.

The same usage is mentioned in the Snowflake documented as well, however you can file an enhancement request at https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas.

1. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-tabular-functions.html

2.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions.html#examples-with-joins

3.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/_autosummary/snowflake.snowpark.udtf.html

Thanks,
Sujan

Answer (score 0):

At present the input parameters to the Snowflake UDTF are constant, it can not be dynamically obtained.

Comment: Is there a workaround ? can't use stored procedure here due to other limitations with snowflake. My current sql uses filters from dashboard settings which can not be passed in as arguments to the procedure! I was trying to accommodate the task dependents scenario as part of this same sql